# Refresh SQL Server References

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlclr

I have a SQL Server project in VS 2010 that references an assembly in a SQL Server 2008 database. If I drop and recreate the assembly in the database with a new version, how can I refresh Visual Studio's view of the reference, so that Intellisense picks up the changes?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that if you follow these steps, the new version of the assembly *should* get picked up by VS:

1. Build > Build Solution
2. Build > Rebuild Solution

Hope this helps!

Comment: This isn't working for me, sorry. I won't downvote, because it may well work for someone else.

Answer (score 0):

The answer might come toooo late, but for me it only worked deleting the reference and adding it again. (10 seconds operation)